# "Точка зрения" и "угол зрения" - в чем разница?

Tags: лексика, фразеология

**Точка зрения**. Устойчивое сочетание (фразеологизм).
*Перен.* Взгляд на кого-либо или на что-либо; оценка кого-либо или чего-либо (определенный взгляд на вещи, то или иное отношение к чему-л.).
***Синонимы***: взгляды, воззрения, убеждения, позиция, принципы, суждение, соображение, взгляд, воззрение, представление, мнение, ***угол зрения***, аспект, понятие.
[**точка зрения**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-86412.htm)

**Угол зрения** (фразеологизм). *Книжн*. Определёный взгляд на те или иные явления, определённое их понимание.
***Синонимы***: аспект, взгляд, воззрение, мнение, ***точка зрения***, позиция,  соображение, суждение.
[**угол зрения**](http://phraseology.academic.ru/13092/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Получается, что фразеологизмы ***точка зрения*** и ***угол зрения*** синонимичны.
Но тождественны ли они? Можно ли "безболезненно" заменить их друг другом?

Answer (score 2):

Ну если верить словарю, то это не полные синонимы, первое относится к общелитературным фразеологизмам, второе - к книжным. Этого уже достаточно чтобы говорить ***о неполной взаимозаменяемости***.

Я бы еще добавил, хотя со мной опять могут не согласиться, что "угол зрения" используется в основном в сочетании "под определенным углом зрения", а "точка" - "с точки зрения такого-то". Здесь их трудно заменить друг другом.

Answer (score 2):

По определению точка зрения (в пространстве) и угол (луч или направление) зрения — разные понятия, не синонимичные. Точка зрения человека на многое в жизни устойчива. Она принципиально не может меняться без внутреннего преобразования человека.

Поменять угол зрения на какой-либо объект значит рассматривать его в другой среде или другом ракурсе — в ином предметном состоянии, в действительности или умозрительно. Для этого человеку необходимо иметь некоторый опыт и воображение.

Answer (score 2):

Угол зрения и точка зрения **не являются близкими синонимами** и далеко не всегда заменяют друг друга в текстах.

**1) В физике:**

**Точка зрения** ― место, где находится наблюдатель и от которого зависит видимая им перспектива.

**Углом зрения** называют угол, составленный прямыми, проведенными из оптического центра глаза к крайним точкам предмета.

Наблюдатель может изменить **угол зрения**, не меняя места, а просто повернув голову. Например: Доллары нового образца  легче всего проверить, изменив **угол зрения** на цифру номинала. [Осторожно, фальшивка! (2003).

**2) В жизни и философии:**

**Точка зрения** ― жизненная позиция, с которой субъект оценивает происходящие вокруг него события. Точка зрения ― это мнение по какому-либо вопросу, которое может быть обосновано и аргументировано.

**Угол зрения** ― это тоже позиция, мнение, суждение, взгляд. Но можно ожидать, что угол зрения на какой-то предмет **также можно изменить, не меняя своих основных жизненных убеждений.**

**Примеры:**

Я понимаю, что всегда есть другой **угол зрения**, при котором чьи-то странности оборачиваются несомненным достоинством. [Алексей Мокроусов. Из инета с любовью (2002) // «Домовой», 2002.10.04]

**Измените угол зрения** и попробуйте взглянуть на вещи с другой стороны. [Татьяна Шохина. Что делать с плохим настроением (2002) // «Семейный доктор», 2002.05.15]